# Adding checked checkboxes to an array and removing the unchecked ones - react native

Tags: react-native

What I need to do is - add/remove the name of each checkbox(which are checked/unchecked by the user) in an array and send to the server. I am stuck in the following code. Any help is appreciated. Thankyou

```
class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ padding: 15 }}>
        {
            response.map(
              item => {
                return (
                  <CheckBoxItem label={item.name} />
                );
              }
            )
        }
       </View>
    );
  }
}
```

CheckBoxItem.js

```
class CheckBoxItem extends Component<Props> {
  state = {
    check: false,
    problemTypeArray: [],
  }

  changeArray = (label) => {
      let array = [...this.state.problemTypeArray, label];
      let index = array.indexOf(label);
      console.log('array', array);//returns array with length 1 all the time
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <CheckBox value={this.state.check} onValueChange={(checkBoolean) => { this.setState({ check: checkBoolean }); this.changeArray(this.props.label); }} />
        <MyText>{this.props.label}</MyText>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default CheckBoxItem;
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? or post your code on snack.expo.io ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real trick to this is to maintain a list of the selected items in the parent component. Each `CheckBoxItem` can control its own state but you will need to pass a value back to the parent component each time it is checked/unchecked.

As you haven't shown where your `CheckBox` component has come from, I will show you how to do it using the `react-native-elements` `CheckBox`. The principles can then be applied to your own `CheckBox`.

Here is the `App.js`

```
import CheckBoxItem from './CheckBoxItem'

export default class App extends React.Component {

  // set some initial values in state
  state = {
    response: [
      {
        name:'first'
      },
            {
        name:'second'
      },
            {
        name:'third'
      },
      {
        name:'fourth'
      },
            {
        name:'fifth'
      },
            {
        name:'sixth'
      },
    ],
    selectedBoxes: [] // this array will hold the names of the items that were selected
  }

  onUpdate = (name) => {
    this.setState(previous => {
      let selectedBoxes = previous.selectedBoxes;
      let index = selectedBoxes.indexOf(name) // check to see if the name is already stored in the array
      if (index === -1) {
        selectedBoxes.push(name) // if it isn't stored add it to the array
      } else {
        selectedBoxes.splice(index, 1) // if it is stored then remove it from the array
      }
      return { selectedBoxes }; // save the new selectedBoxes value in state
    }, () => console.log(this.state.selectedBoxes)); // check that it has been saved correctly by using the callback function of state
  }

  render() {
    const { response } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {
          response.map(item => <CheckBoxItem label={item.name} onUpdate={this.onUpdate.bind(this,item.name)}/>)
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the `CheckBoxItem`

```
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements'

class CheckBoxItem extends Component<Props> {
  state = {
    check: false, // by default lets start unchecked
  }

  onValueChange = () => {
    // toggle the state of the checkbox
    this.setState(previous => {
      return  { check: !previous.check }
    }, () => this.props.onUpdate()); 
    // once the state has been updated call the onUpdate function
    // which will update the selectedBoxes array in the parent componetn
  } 

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <CheckBox 
          title={this.props.label}
          checked={this.state.check} 
          onPress={this.onValueChange} 
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default CheckBoxItem;
```

## Explanation

When a `CheckBoxItem` is created two things are passed to it. One is a label and the second is an `onUpdate` function. The `onUpdate` function links the `CheckBoxItem` back to the parent component so that it can manipulate the state in the parent.

The `onUpdate` function takes the previous value of the state, before this update is applied, and it looks to see if the name of the checkbox exists in the `selectedBoxes` array. If it exists in the `selectedBoxes` array it is removed, otherwise it is added.

Now there exists an array in the parent component that you can access that contains all that items that have been selected.

## Snack

Want to try out my code? Well I have created a snack that shows it working https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/checkboxes

## Setting state

You may have noticed that I am doing some unusual things with `setState`. I am making sure that `setState` gets called properly by using the previous value of the state and then applying my updates to that. I am also using the fact that `setState` takes a callback to perform actions after the state has been updated. If you would like to read more here are some great articles on `setState`.

- https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-is-asynchronous-52ead919a3f0
- https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296
- https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-function-56eb940f84b6