# Remove item when unchecked checkbox

Tags: javascript, react-native, checkbox

I have checkbox with a couple item in it, when i click the check box the item will add to state called currentDevice, but when i unchecked the item it keep add item and not remove it.

How do i remove item from state when i unchecked the box. Im using react-native-element checkbox. Thankyou before

The code:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
currentDevice: [],
checked: []
 }
}

handleChange = (index, item) => {
    let checked = [...this.state.checked];
    checked[index] = !checked[index];
    this.setState({ checked });

    this.setState({currentDevice: [...this.state.currentDevice, item.bcakId]})
  }

renderFlatListDevices = (item, index) => {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
      <CheckBox
        title={item.label || item.bcakId}
        checked={this.state.checked[index]}
        onPress={() => {this.handleChange(index, item)}}
        checkedIcon='dot-circle-o'
        uncheckedIcon='circle-o'
        checkedColor='#FFE03A'
        containerStyle={styles.containerCheckBox}
        textStyle={styles.textCheckBox}
      />
    </ScrollView>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, here is the code :

```
handleChange = (index, item) => {
    let checked = [...this.state.checked];
    checked[index] = !checked[index];
    this.setState({ checked });
    this.setState(previous => {
      let currentDevice = previous.currentDevice;
      let index = currentDevice.indexOf(item.bcakId)
      if (index === -1) {
        currentDevice.push(item.bcakId)
      } else {
        currentDevice.splice(index, 1)
      }
      return { currentDevice }
    }, () => console.log(this.state.currentDevice));
  }
```

Credit : [Adding checked checkboxes to an array and removing the unchecked ones - react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54989545/adding-checked-checkboxes-to-an-array-and-removing-the-unchecked-ones-react-na)

Answer (score 1):

change the handleChange method to

```
const handleChange = (index, item) => {
  const {currentDevice, checked} = state;
  const found = currentDevice.some((data) => data === item.bcakId);
  if (found) {
    currentDevice.splice(
      currentDevice.findIndex((data) => data === item.bcakId),
      1
    );
  } else {
    currentDevice.push(item.bcakId);
  }
  checked[index] = !checked[index];
  this.setState({
    currentDevice,
    checked,
  })
};
```